# CSS Borders and border-radius for text

Tags: css

I came across this trick when I wanted to feature some headline text. I love the look of it as was wondering if there was a way to have the ends point up.

```
.pagebreaker {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border-top: 4px solid #f6d241;
    border-radius: 35px;
  }
```

ref Image:
[image: Page Section Divider]

I've tried negative border-radius and negative padding. Is there something I am missing here? Or is this something that can't be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-bottom`

```css
.pagebreaker {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f6d241;
    border-radius: 35px;
    
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pagebreaker"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Gerard,

That worked, thank you for your help on this...I really appreciate it.